# how to splice selected element from FileList

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

[image: here is my multipart form selected files]

selected files preview with fileReader in javascript

> if i remove from previewed image. it must delete from selected files!

```
$scope.getFile = function () {
    $scope.progress = 0;
    $scope.variant.images = [];
    var files = $scope.file;
    for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        fileReader.readAsDataUrl(file, $scope).then(function(result) {
            $scope.variant.images.push({path: result})


        });
    }
};
```

i try like this but it does not works

```
angular.forEach($scope.file, function (value, key) {
        if(key === id){
            delete value;
        }
    })
```

Comment: Can we see the controller and html code? What unique indentifier are you using to identify the object you'd like to delete?

Comment: Any luck with the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot splice a [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileList). It is readonly! It only has the `length` and `item` but no array logic like `splice', 'split`., etc. So you will have to make a copy from it in an array:

```
// **A**
$scope.fileArray = [];
angular.forEach($scope.file, function(file) {
    $scope.fileArray.push(file)
});
```

And then you can splice from this array with something like:

```
$scope.deleteImage = function(index) {
   $scope.fileArray.splice(index, 1);
})
```

As you mention 'preview' I guess you are displaying a thumbnail of the selected images. You will have to change any display logic also to use the `fileArray` instead of the current `file`. So it automatically updates when the user removes one element.

```
<div ng-repeat="image in fileArray"... >
```

So best to set up an angular watch to recalculate `$scope.fileArray` as given above. However I'm afraid you cannot do a $watch on a file list. Not certain, but I recently found out that Angular does NOT support `ng-model` on a `<input type="file"`. I found a solution for this in [this article](https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs).

So if a simple `$scope.$watch('file', function..` doesn't work, you'd best import use the `fileModel` directive in that into your system and enhance the file-input in your view with it:

```
<input type="file" name="files" file-model="filesArray" multiple accept="image"/>
```

You should then be able to watch that filesArray you assign to it:

```
$scope.$watch('fileArray', function() {
    // Code from **A**
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native JS Array#forEach function as it gives you access the index of the object in the array.

I used `id` assuming you are actually passing an `id` in to the function to identify the object that needs to be deleted from the array. Looking at your code above, `name` seems more ideal, if that's unique property in the object of course

```
$scope.file.forEach(function(file, index){

    if (file.id === id){ // Where id is your identifier, could be file.name === name.
        this.splice(index, 1);
    }

});
```